# Deduce LP maximization problem from sensitivity analysis

Tags: linear-programming

I have the answer to and the sensitivity analysis for a LP maximization problem. (See picture)

http://postimg.org/image/xs4iowbrj/

How can I deduce the original LP problem?

I have figured out this:

Max Z = 5x1 + 4x2 + 3x3 + 4x4

a1x1 + b1x2 + c1x3 + d1x4 <= 40

a2x1 + b2x2 + c2x3 + d2x4 <= 30

But I don't know how to deduce a1...d2.
Thanks

Comment: I dont´t think, that you have only these tables. What is the original exercise ?

Comment: This is the original exercise. It is possible, and if I remember correctly you have to use "final value" under "variable cells" in the sensitivity analysis (first picture) along with the shadow price.

Comment: But there should be a problem described.  For example, what does "produksjon:kaffekaker" mean ? Is it the amount of produced coffee named kaker ? What is the context ? Keep in mind, that we have only the linked pictures-nothing else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I uploaded the wrong picture. 

This is an exam problem, and there is no other given context. Not that it matters anyway; all excel sensitivity analysis are in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible. I'm getting close, but I need help the rest of the way.

I'm able to find the constants for one of the constraints using reduced cost and shadow price from the [sensitivity report](http://postimg.org/image/xs4iowbrj/). 
Lets redefine our problem so it becomes clearer:

Max Z = 5x1 + 4x2 + 3x3 + 4x4

a11*x1 + a12*x2 + a13*x3 + a14*x4 <= 40

a21*x1 + a22*x2 + a23*x3 + a24*x4 <= 30

Let y1 and y2 be the shadow price for constraints 1 and 2.

Let r1..r4 be the reduced cost for x1..x4.

Let c1..c4 be the constants for the max problem (here 5, 4, 3, 4).

Then:

r1 = c1 - (a11*y1 + a21*y2)

r2 = c2 - (a12*y1 + a22*y2)

and so on.
([Source](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwiZzPjkn5DHAhXlEXIKHTw3Ais&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2F15.053%2Fwww%2FAMP-Chapter-03.pdf&ei=Ch7BVZmfCOWjyAO87ojYAg&usg=AFQjCNH45DeILbIvKJkO7OrelSWrOHHFjg&sig2=SY9DItWu8-rUfhxVcgzlWA&bvm=bv.99261572,d.bGQ) page 80)

Since the shadow price is 0 for constraint 1 (y1=0) this gives

a21 = 6, a22=4, a23=4, a24=4

The second constraint then becomes

6*x1 + 4*x2 + 4*x3 + 4*x4 <= 30

How can I find the constants for the first constraint?

(According to the exam solution, it's supposed to be a11..a14 = 4, 6, 4, 2)